# Explain error log output type [debug], and what service is causing it

Tags: php, logging, nginx

Did an apt-get update and now my error logs are flooded with [debug] type output. I've never seen this type of output, so I'm having trouble figuring out where to start. I have error reporting set to `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`

Sample Log output:

```
2016/02/05 13:04:28 [debug] 2960#0: *7 http fastcgi record byte: 08
2016/02/05 13:04:28 [debug] 2960#0: *7 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2016/02/05 13:04:28 [debug] 2960#0: *7 http fastcgi record length: 8
2016/02/05 13:04:28 [debug] 2960#0: *7 http fastcgi sent end request
2016/02/05 13:04:28 [debug] 2960#0: *7 input buf 00007FBBE71A0F4D 79
2016/02/05 13:04:28 [debug] 2960#0: *7 pipe write downstream: 1
2016/02/05 13:04:28 [debug] 2960#0: *7 pipe write downstream flush in
```